woo commerce API - return orders by billing number
I am building a dashboard that is not located in the WordPress installation, I want to return all orders that match as specific billing number.
I will most likely be using a CURL request via a php script as that seems like the easiest option.
I have been testing with the api through insomnia and I am able to do what I want by using the search query as follows:
/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?search=mobilenumber
But I don't want to search all values, I want to be able to target a specific attribute "billing" "phone".
Thanks
I have tried various query strings to get the results but the API documentation doesn't have what I want to do listed in the parameters.
I have tried added the following code in functions php and making the following request, but I don't get filtered results:
wp-json/wc/v3/orders?billing_phone=number
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_shop_order_object_query', 'filter_orders_by_billing_phone', 999, 2 );
function filter_orders_by_billing_phone( $args, $request ) {
    if ( ! isset( $request['billing_phone'] ) ) {
        return $args;
    }
    
    $source_value = sanitize_text_field( $request['billing_phone'] );
    $source_meta_query = array(
        'key' => 'billing_phone',
        'value' => $source_value
    );
    
    if ( isset( $args['meta_query'] ) ) {
        $args['meta_query']['relation'] = 'AND';
        $args['meta_query'][] = $source_meta_query;
    } else {
        $args['meta_query'] = array();
        $args['meta_query'][] = $source_meta_query;
    }
    
    return $args;


I had noticed this and tested it. I don't understand why it is there. Thanks for your input.

The code above in my question actually works. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong during testing.postes again below.
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_shop_order_object_query', 'filter_orders_by_billing_phone', 999, 2 );
function filter_orders_by_billing_phone( $args, $request ) {
    if ( ! isset( $request['billing_phone'] ) ) {
        return $args;
    }
    
    $source_value = sanitize_text_field( $request['billing_phone'] );
    $source_meta_query = array(
        'key' => 'billing_phone',
        'value' => $source_value
    );
    
    if ( isset( $args['meta_query'] ) ) {
        $args['meta_query']['relation'] = 'AND';
        $args['meta_query'][] = $source_meta_query;
    } else {
        $args['meta_query'] = array();
        $args['meta_query'][] = $source_meta_query;
    }
    
    return $args;


Then consider deleting the question instead of posting this as an answer?

I couldn't find the reference for billing phone anywhere, shouldn't I leave it up for anyone else looking?

Consider creating a new question on how to fetch records by the billing phone and post the code as an answer?
